# Making a specific cell of a dynamically generated tikz matrix BOLD

Tags: tikz-pgf, bold, pgfmath, tikz-matrix

I want to make specific cells of a dynamically generated tikz matrix **bold**. I have tried many things: `\bfseries`, `\mathbf`, `\textbf`, `\bf`, using `assume math mode=false` in `\pgfmathprintnumberto` ...

Here is my MWE. (Note that I have replaced my calculations with `\pgfmathparse{exp 2}` and this MWE is a very small part of my original code. I have not added the code that determines which cells will be bold.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\newcommand{\calculate}[1]{
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}%
\pgfmathparse{exp 2}%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
\global\let\totsum\pgfmathresult%
\foreach \i in {0,...,5} {
    \gappto\mymatrixcontent{A}
    \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\mymatrixcontent\expandafter{\&}%
    \pgfmathprintnumberto[/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2]{\totsum}{\fsum}%
    \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\mymatrixcontent\expandafter{\fsum}%
    \gappto\mymatrixcontent{\\}
}
}
\calculate{1}
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (mat) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&]{
    \mymatrixcontent
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

I need one line of code like this:

```
\expandafter\gappto\expandafter\mymatrixcontent\expandafter{\textbf\fsum}
```

that makes `\fsum` **bold**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it if you add in a few more `\expandafter` commands.

```
 \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\mymatrixcontent\expandafter{%
   \expandafter$\expandafter\mathbf\expandafter{\fsum}$}%
```

If you ignore the `\expandafter` commands for a moment, then this is essentially the same as `$\mathbf{\fsum}$`. The simpler version `\textbf{\fsum}` doesn't seem to work, and I don't know why, but maybe a knowledgeable person will chime in with a comment `:-)`.

### Output

[image]

### Complete code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active, tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\newcommand{\calculate}[1]{
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}%
\pgfmathparse{exp 2}%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
\global\let\totsum\pgfmathresult%
\foreach \i in {0,...,5} {
    \gappto\mymatrixcontent{A}
    \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\mymatrixcontent\expandafter{\&}%
    \pgfmathprintnumberto[/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2]{\totsum}{\fsum}%
\expandafter\gappto\expandafter\mymatrixcontent\expandafter{%
   \expandafter$\expandafter\mathbf\expandafter{\fsum}$}%
    \gappto\mymatrixcontent{\\}
}
}
\calculate{1}
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (mat) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&]{
    \mymatrixcontent
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the current construction has the specific order but same functionality can be achieved via slightly simpler append method. Also `fpu` library is not required for such computations since you are truncating down to two decimal digits and TeX accuracy is sufficient for that.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\calculate}[1]{
\let\mymatrixcontent\empty
\pgfmathparse{exp(#1)}%
\pgfmathprintnumberto[fixed,precision=2,zerofill,
                      assume math mode=true]{\pgfmathresult}{\fsum}%
\let\ea\expandafter%
    \foreach \i in {0,...,5} {%
        \g@addto@macro\mymatrixcontent{A\&}%
        \ea\g@addto@macro\ea\mymatrixcontent\ea{\ea$\ea\mathbf\ea{\fsum}$}%
        %\ea\g@addto@macro\ea\mymatrixcontent\ea{\ea\textbf\ea{\fsum}}% <- For \textbf{}
        \g@addto@macro\mymatrixcontent{\\}%
    }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\calculate{1}
  \matrix (mat) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&]{
    \mymatrixcontent
  };

\calculate{4}
  \matrix (mat2) at(mat.east)[anchor=west,matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&]{
    \mymatrixcontent
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The reason why `\textbf` doesn't work in John's answer is that `\pgfmathprintnumber` has a default `\ensuremath` builtin the number printing mechanism. Hence `\textbf` doesn't penetrate into the math environment. You can turn it off by providing the `assume math mode=true` option.

[image]